# How to get submit button on same line as input?

Tags: css, forms, input

I am wanting my search button to align with my input field when on desktop. When it scales it is fine if it drops below the input field but it does need to be scalable. Right now it is automatically sitting under the input form so I know it is something to do with my styling because without it, it will align right next to the field. Here's a [codepen] (https://codepen.io/miller765/pen/YMzPKJ) along with the code.

```css
form.searchbar {
  margin: 25px 50px;
}

.searchMe {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(0, 91, 148);
  color: white;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 1.0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Arial Sans;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.searchMe:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 57, 99);
}
```

```html
<form id="" class="searchbar" action="searchAppt.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="terms" style="width: 300px" size="40" class="sbar" placeholder="Search..." oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" onblur="if (this.value == '') {
                                       this.value = '';
                                   }" onfocus="if (this.value == '') {
                                       this.value = '';
                                   }" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button type="submit" style="width: 100px" class="searchMe">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello @TMiller96   if you just remove the display:block  its already aligned but check my answer plz if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `.searchMe {display: block}` to `inline-block`

[updated copepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xePxXa)

```css
form.searchbar {
  margin: 25px 50px;
}

.searchMe {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(0, 91, 148);
  color: white;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 1.0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Arial Sans;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.searchMe:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 57, 99);
}
```

```html
<form id="" class="searchbar" action="searchAppt.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="terms" style="width: 300px" size="40" class="sbar" placeholder="Search..." oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" onblur="if (this.value == '') {
                                       this.value = '';
                                   }" onfocus="if (this.value == '') {
                                       this.value = '';
                                   }" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button type="submit" style="width: 100px" class="searchMe">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `display: inline;` to your .searchMe you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```css
form.searchbar {
  margin: 25px 50px;
}

.searchMe {
  background-color: rgb(0, 91, 148);
  color: white;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 1.0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Arial Sans;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.searchMe:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 57, 99);
}
```

```html
<form id="" class="searchbar" action="searchAppt.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="terms" style="width: 300px" size="40" class="sbar" placeholder="Search..." oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" onblur="if (this.value == '') {
                                       this.value = '';
                                   }" onfocus="if (this.value == '') {
                                       this.value = '';
                                   }" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button type="submit" style="width: 100px" class="searchMe">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello just add `display: inline-block;` to .searchMe class
Check the demo below

```css
form.searchbar {
      margin: 25px 50px;
    }

    .searchMe {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: rgb(0, 91, 148);
      color: white;
      padding: 1px 3px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: auto;
      opacity: 1.0;
      border-radius: 5px;
      font-family: Arial Sans;
      font-size: 1em;
    }

    .searchMe:hover {
      background-color: rgb(0, 57, 99);
    }
```

```html
<form id="" class="searchbar" action="searchAppt.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="terms" style="width: 300px" size="40" class="sbar" placeholder="Search..." oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" onblur="if (this.value == '') {
                                       this.value = '';
                                   }" onfocus="if (this.value == '') {
                                       this.value = '';
                                   }" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button type="submit" style="width: 100px" class="searchMe">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just remove display:block it will be aligned you dont have to use inline . Now if you want  you can target form.searchbar{display:flex;} even when it scales it stays  aligned

```css
form.searchbar {
  margin: 25px 50px;
  display:flex;
}

.searchMe {
  display:block;
  background-color: rgb(0, 91, 148);
  color: white;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 1.0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Arial Sans;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.searchMe:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 57, 99);
}
```

```html
<form id="" class="searchbar" action="searchAppt.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="terms" style="width: 300px" size="40" class="sbar" placeholder="Search..." oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" onblur="if (this.value == '') {
                                       this.value = '';
                                   }" onfocus="if (this.value == '') {
                                       this.value = '';
                                   }" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button type="submit" style="width: 100px" class="searchMe">Search</button>
</form>
```